# Google Drive not downloading any files

Tags: google-drive

I am using Chrome Version 53.0.2785.101 m (latest update). Every time I click on download file it says "Scanning for viruses" after which it's supposed to start the download. Well, it doesn't.

How can I fix it? I don't want to use another browser or to download the G. Drive app just because of that.

Comment: Have you tried on a different network? Have you tried a different browser? I know you don't want to use something else, but if it's the browser that's the problem then that'll be your only option (until Google fixes it).

Comment: @Ventzi Try in incognito mode with all the extensions turned off. If that fails, try with another browser to check if it's a browser problem or if it's due to something else.

Answer (score 2):

POSSIBLE SOLUTION (don't shoot the messenger) - But I had an issue downloading from Google Drive. I would click to download, it scans for virus, and then nothing...no download started. But then I stumbled on this. I right click the item I want to download and click to "get link", then copy and paste the url. Finally, on this screen you will see the download icon in the top right. Click it and it should prompt you to save the file in your selected file location. File has been downloaded, crisis adverted, *smokes blunt* and gets back to life.

Hope it helps any lost soul searching for this answer from a question asked, at the moment, 4 years ago. If you see this in the future, people are currently wearing masks, all confused on everything.

Comment: Blunt has been smoketh. Take my upvote!